# C# - shorten function calls

Tags: c#, function, class, call, nested-class

I have a `.dll` file from which I call functions in another program, however calling a single function ends up looking like this:

Example:

```
KeySim.KeySim.Basic.KEY_E();
```

I cannot modify the nesting of the classes as the program ceases to work.
I was wondering if there was any other way to shorten the code calling the functions

Note:

`Keysim` is the namespace, `Keysim` is the main class and `Basic` is a nested class

Comment: `using KeySim;` to get rid of the namespace at least.

Comment: To be honest, `KeySim.KeySim.Basic.KEY_E()` is quite short.

Comment: What if you just call method from your own methods like  ---  void KeY_E() { KeySim.KeySim.Basic.KEY_E(); }     ?

Comment: Create a method that calls your lengthy code. Use that method wherever you want to call that code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `Alias` with the `using` keyword:

```
using Basic = KeySim.KeySim.Basic;
```

Then you should be able to call your function as:

```
Basic.KEY_E();
```